# Unity Physics performance spikes while updating even a single box collider size at runtime

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, garbage-collection, game-physics, profiler

Unity version : 2020.2.3

I am working on a Evo Pop style game where I have to scale up the cubes at runtime. I am developing a basic prototype of it, I found that even with single cube on terrain, it hits huge spikes if I scale up the cube at runtime.

It generates GC of 0.6kb every frame until the cube is growing (scaling up). Also the Physics.Processing takes around 87%

How to optimize the physics collision when your colliders are scaling up & down at runtime?

Screenshot : profiler
[image]

Screenshot : physics settings
[image]

Screenshot : rigidbody settings

[image]

Comment: can you share your code for the scaling as well?

Comment: @maxidevstuff

Code image link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/jor70avqjf8r1pe/3.png?dl=0

I am using a simple coroutine to scale up the cube until it gets double the size

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `Tween` from [Surge Package(Free)](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/surge-107312)

```
using UnityEngine;
using PixelPlacement;

void ScaleMyBlock(float ScaleOffset)
{
        Tween.LocalScale (transform, initialScale , Vector3.one * ScaleOffset, 1, 0, Tween.linear, Tween.LoopType.None, null, null);
}
```

You can read more about it [here.](http://surge.pixelplacement.com/tween.html)